# How to complete filenames relative to another directory?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

This is a follow-up question to the discussion in:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1394920

Suppose I have a folder `~/tmp` with some files and directories:

```
$ mkdir a; touch file1.txt; mkdir a/b; mkdir a/c; touch a/d; mkdir a/b/c
```

I now try to make a completion script to complete filenames in `~/tmp`, but the `complete -o filenames` option is only working correctly if the current directory is `~/tmp`.

See the above link for more background information. This is as far as I got:

```
$ cat setup
_compTest() {
    local cur baseFolder
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"
    baseFolder=~/tmp
    compopt -o nospace
    COMPREPLY=(  $(
       cd "$baseFolder"
       if [[ ${cur: -1} != "/" && -d $cur ]] ; then
           echo "$cur/"
       else
           compgen -f "$cur"
       fi
      )  )
}
complete -F _compTest aaa
```

Then I source it:

```
$ . setup
```

and I can then do

```
$ aaa <tab><tab>
```

- Problem 1 : Slashes are not added at the end of directory names in the completion list ( this is desired to easy separate directories from file names in the completion list)
- Problem 2 : For `aaa a/<tab><tab>` the completion list is `a/b  a/c  a/d` but the `a/` prefix should not be there. It should be `b/ c/ d` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would write this function as:

```
_compTest () 
{ 
    local cur; local tmp;  local tmp_escaped; local i;
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur;
    local _compreply=()
    tmp=~/tmp/
    tmp_escaped=${tmp//\//\\\/}
    cur=$tmp$cur;

    if [ "$1" == "-d" ]; then
        _cd
    else
        _filedir;
    fi;
    for i in "${COMPREPLY[@]}"; do
        [ -d "$i" ] && [ "$i" != "$tmp." ] && [ "$i" != "$tmp.." ] && i="$i/"
        _compreply=("${_compreply[@]}" "$i")
    done

    COMPREPLY=(${_compreply[@]/$tmp_escaped/})
} && complete -o nospace -F _compTest aaa_files

_compTestDir()
{
    _compTest -d
} && complete -o nospace -F _compTestDir aaa_directories
```

It has 3 parts,

1. prefixing the `$cur` with your base directory - ~/tmp.
2. Using standard bash completion routine `_filedir` used for cd/ls etc.
3. Removing `~/tmp` from `COMPREPLY`

Just for the record: You can use this logic to complete the file names relative to many other *types* of path, e.g.

1. I use it to complete perforce paths `//...`.
2. You can also complete `http://localhost/*` paths, relative to your `public_html` directory.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! How do I define `_get_comp_words_by_ref` ? ( I get `_get_comp_words_by_ref: command not found` )

Comment: I think I found it : `source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` ?

Comment: It is not working yet, I just get a series of slashes when typing `aaa <tab><tab>`.. What is the purpose of this `if [ "$1" == "-d" ]` ? (I think $1 would be `aaa`, so why compare with `"-d"` ? )

Comment: `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` (usually) gets sourced by default on `bash` on many distros (at least on ubuntu). Not exactly sure, which is the nested path by which it gets sourced.

Comment: I still get the same behavior.. What is the purpose of the `&&` and `aaa_files` and `aaa_directories` in the `complete` command?

Comment: aaa_files was for you to test the function _compTest for files & aaa_directories was for you to test the function _compTest for directories.

Comment: "It is not working yet, I just get a series of slashes when typing aaa <tab><tab>.. " Please update the question with the output of `ls -F ~/tmp`

Comment: Ok, I see :) Now `aaa_files <tab><tab>` gives one slash for each tab press.. and `aaa_directories <tab><tab>` gives a slash for the first tab press, and then, for the next tab press, lists the contents of the root folder as possible completions... `ls -F ~/tmp` gives `"a/  file1.txt"`

Comment: Does `complete -F _compTest aaa` with above `_compTest` code not solve your problem?

Comment: Got the problem. & you were right about "I think $1 would be aaa" part :-)

Comment: Hi anishsane! I then still wonder why the function has this test: `if [ "$1" == "-d" ]` .. if `$1 == "aaa_files"` why test against `-d` ? Is there anything I am missing here? Ok, I think I got it.. it is for the command `aaa_directories`, right? Then `$1` becomes `-d` ?

Comment: Ok, I tested the new function a little bit now. Unfortunately, it is not working as desired yet. First I need only one command: either `aaa_files` or `aaa_directories`, second: for the `aaa_files` command: If I type `aaa_files a<tab>` it gives me `aaa_files a/<space>`. It should not give a <space> after the slash /, but instead give `aaa_files a/` and then a completion list with three items: `b/ c/ d` ...

Comment: Ok :)  I will test it, but first what is `/dev/pts/26`?

Comment: It seems that `aaa_files` is getting closer to a solution now, but `aaa_directories` is not looking at `~/tmp` at all, but rather the current directory. There is still the following problems with `aaa_files`: If I type `aaa_files <tab><tab>` it gives a completion list with two entries: `// .txt`. This is obviously wrong, it should be `a file1.txt`. If I ignore this, and type `aaa_files /<tab>` it seems to be more correct behavior..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66407/discussion-between-anishsane-and-hakon-haegland).

Comment: I missed one `/` while editing the answer :-( Fixed.

Comment: Is there any particular reason against just setting the working directory with `pushd`, letting `_filedir` do its thing and then restoring the directory with `popd` (with some error checking for when `pushd` fails for any reason, like a non-existent directory, and some additional fine-tuning for the slashes)?

Comment: @Taederias, because it's not needed. You can get the same effect by just adjusting the `cur` variable.

Comment: @anishsane Fair enough, thanks for answering! The reason I was considering that is because at first glace, without looking much deeper into the code, I wasn't sure if any of the special processing of quotes/escaping in the argument the shell does is potentially going to mess with just adding and removing the prefix. (Like how the shell appears to know if there is an open quote, or special characters are being backslash-escaped and complete the argument accordingly, but on multiple matches, the list presented is literal... so I didn't know what I will really find in `COMPLREPLY`.)

Comment: Hmm. Fair point. I use it mainly for completing paths relative to perforce root. For source codes, we usually don't use special characters. So, my solution above may not be bulletproof; but it works for my requirement. For complex directory names, it may need some fixes.

Comment: Yeah, my use case was a script that (among other things) can take an argument for a "root" directory, then take some files inside selected via their relative paths and copy them to a destination directory, replicating these relative paths there as well. A straightforward task, but getting completion to behave well on the relative paths with respect to the already given root is a bit tricky if one wants to account for all the weirdness that can (in theory) be present in filenames and user input, and leads to getting entangled in some potentially undocumented stuff, for very little real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Would have added as a comment, but I don't have the reputation...

Building on @anishsane's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27244662/7770351), if there is only a single completion option and it is not a directory, then you may **not** want to include the `nospace` option.  For example, the program may accept another argument after the one you are currently completing.  If there is only one option, we should accept that option and move on to the next arg.

To do this, remove `nospace` from the `complete` line and add logic to enable `nospace` only when needed:

```
    # [...]

    # Do not include trailing space in results if there is more than one option
    # or if the only option is a directory
    [ "${#_compreply[@]}" -gt 1 ] && compopt -o nospace
    [ "${#_compreply[@]}" -eq 1 ] && [ -d "${_compreply[0]}" ] && compopt -o nospace

    COMPREPLY=(${_compreply[@]/$tmp_escaped/})
} && complete -F _compTest aaa_files
```